# ¿Cómo puedo sacar el número mayor del vector?

Tags: java

```java
package vectorpractica;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Vector {

    public void llenar(int x, char vec[]) {
        if (x < 10) {
            vec[x] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Digite un número:").charAt(0);
            llenar(x + 1, vec);

        }
    }

    public void mostrar(int x, char vec[]) {
        if (x < 10) {
            System.out.print(vec[x] + " ");
            mostrar(x + 1, vec);
        }
    }

    public void mayor(int x, char vec[]) {
        mayor = int x;
        if (x <mayor) {
            System.out.println("El número mayor es: " + vec[x]);
        }
    }

}
```

¿Cómo puedo sacar el número mayor de este vector en el void mayor que se encuentra del último que está incorrecto?

Comment: me podrias explicar que trataste de hacer con ese codigo? de paso, como sacarias el numero mayor de cualquier cosa, en papel?

Comment: deberías aplicar algún ciclo repetitivo para poder iterar el array sea for o while..

Answer (score 0):

Creo que podría funcionar con esto

```
public void mayor(int x, int vec[]) {
    Arrays.sort(vec);
    System.out.println("El número mayor es: " + vec[x-1]);
}
```

Utilizas el método sort para ordenar de menor a mayor y ya simplemente imprimes la última posición del arreglo

Answer (score 0):

Noté que usas recursividad en los métodos `llenar()` y `mostrar()`; los cuales estan bien. Por otro lado, para obtener el número mayor te propongo primero pasar tu arreglo de `char[]` a uno de `int[]`; esto con el objetivo de tener tu cógido más ordenado y puedas comprenderlo.

```
public static int[] charAint(char[] vec) {
    int[] enteros = new int[vec.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.length; i++) {
        enteros[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(vec[i]));
    }
    return enteros;
}

public static void mayor(int[] vec) {
    int mayor = vec[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < vec.length; i++) {
        if (vec[i] > mayor) {
            mayor = vec[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("\nEl número mayor es: %d", mayor);
}
```

Deberás llamar primero a `charAint()` y luego a `mayor()`, pasándole como parámetro el vector de enteros que retornó `charAint()`.